# Redundant conformance with NavigationControllerDelegate

Tags: swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I have an error saying Redundant Conformance to Protocol UINavigationControllerDelegate

So here is my separate pieces of code.

```
class DelegateProfileViewController: FormViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate  {


class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController, UIActionSheetDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, 
 UINavigationControllerDelegate {


class EditSubGroupViewController: FormViewController, SelectUsersFromSubGroupDelegate, SelectSingleFromSubGroupDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {



extension CreateEngagementViewController: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


class FeedViewController: UITableViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, DZNEmptyDataSetSource, DZNEmptyDataSetDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate {
```

You get the point. Each and everyone of these errors come up saying Redundant Conformance of BLANK to protocol UINavigationControllerDelegate.

I would love if someone would tell me why these errors are screwing over my project. Thanks

Comment: does your formviewcontroller or any other controller you made also conform to  UINavigationControllerDelegate?

Comment: @DarkInnocence yes there are four more view controllers that also conform to uinavigationcontrollerdelegate and they get errors too.

Comment: you need to conform it once only, otherwise it gets inherited multiple times, which is the error itself. For ex:- if classA conforms to the delegate and then you do classB: classA, so automatically classB also conforms to the delegate. So, remove the redundant ones

Comment: @DarkInnocence so what view controller should I can form that you are navigation controller delegate to

Comment: didn't get you!

Comment: edit the question with all the class signatures you are using and hopefully I'll be able to figure out.

Comment: @DarkInnocence sorry typo so what viewcontroller should I put uinavigationcontrollerdelegate to so it will be used in all of my viewcontrollers

Comment: so, for ex:-  class DelegateProfileViewController: FormViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
this is you original signature, but if for instance FormViewController has already conformed to the protocol, 
so the signature changes to class DelegateProfileViewController: FormViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate

Comment: Oh ok got it thanks man

Comment: going to post it as answer, accept it as a solution if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll get that error message if a subclass declares conformance to a protocol which is already inherited from a superclass

Taking an example: if in your case FormViewController has already conformed to  UINavigationControllerDelegate

```
class FormViewController: UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

then there is no need to conform to it again by doing this:-

```
class DelegateProfileViewController: FormViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate
```

Instead it should be changed to :-

```
class DelegateProfileViewController: FormViewController, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate
```

This will remove your redundant conformance. Hope you get an idea of what I'm talking about.